# How to Debug Eclipse's "CMake Compilation DB" Provider

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

Above Provider is throwing following error: "A Problem has occured - Parsing compilation database of project ExampleProject"

Is there a way to see get an exact error?

Edit: Error log can be shown by going to "Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Error Log"

But the log isn't helpful at all, see attached screenshot [image]

Comment: Is there only one error logged? Please delete the error log, reproduce the issue, go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (just select, not open the error), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Just with a restart the error occurs three times:
`eclipse.buildId=4.27.0.20230309-1200
java.version=17.0.7
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

org.eclipse.cdt.core
Error
Mon Jun 12 14:27:16 CEST 2023`

Comment: i deactivated the provider and the problem occurs only two times now o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i managed to run cmake from MinGW instead of the cygwin one which resulted in the errors above ("Build Tool Kits"). The overwrite points now to the cygwin version -> fixed